# Minkowski's Inequality for $0<p<1$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I need to prove: for non-negative functions $f,g\in L^p[0,1]$, $||f+g||_p\geq||f||_p+||g||_p$ for $0<p<1$.

For $1\leq p<\infty$, the inequality is reversed and the proof is like:
The cases $||f||_p=0$ or $||g||_p=0$ are trivial. So we assume $||f||_p=\alpha\neq0$ and $||g||_p=\beta\neq0$, then there are functions $f_0,g_0\in L^p$ such that $|f|=\alpha f_0,|g|=\beta g_0$, and  $||f_0||_p=||g_0||_p=1$. Defining $\lambda=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)+g(x)|^p&\leq&(|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^p=[\alpha f_0+\beta g_0]^p~~~~~~~~~~(*)\\
&=&(\alpha+\beta)^p[\lambda f_0(x)+(1-\lambda)g_0(x)]^p\\
&\leq&(\alpha+\beta)^p[\lambda f_0(x)^p+(1-\lambda)g_0(x)^p]~~~~~~~(**)
\end{eqnarray}
by convexity of the function $\phi(t)=t^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$. The rest follows by taking integration of both sides over $[0,1]$.

Now it says in the hint that for the result I want to prove for $0<p<1$, we need only to use the concavity of the function $\phi(t)=t^p$ for $0<p<1$. But that only reverses the inequality for $(**)$ and not $(*)$.

Then how can I prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you want isn't true without some additional hypothesis - maybe $f,g \ge 0$.  Otherwise $f = -g$ is a counterexample.  But my suggested added hypothesis makes your first inequality an equality, and so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: extremely sorry, forgot to mention. $f$ and $g$ are non-negative functions. I edited my question.

Comment: But then you have $|f(x) + g(x)|^p = (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^p$ and your problem is solved.

Comment: Oh! How that escaped me!! That was very helpful!! Thank you!

Comment: You can also mimic the proof of Minkowski that goes via Hoelder's inequality.  But here the conjugate index is negative.  Again the inequality is reversed, and non-negativity is required.